# Command-Line program process png to 18bit

Tags: image, command-line, png

Is there a command-line program that can process pngs(and other formats) to make them 18bit 262k colors. Something like

```
imageprocess -bpp 18bit
```

Comment: Not programming related.

Comment: @Oded
Im making an app that will use this

Comment: You are asking for an existing app. Not how to write one.

Comment: Yes, but this is support for my app. I am asking for "part" of my app and im not writing a 18bit converter because im sure it exists somewhere. Remember, "dont reinvent the wheel"

Comment: Agreed, we are all against reinventing the wheel. But asking for a command line app, does not constitute a programming question, IMHO

Comment: Superuser.com is a sister site for all computer related questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ImageMagick's -depth option should do what you're asking.

http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#depth